# Object variable or With block variable not set in Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro to plot graphs when the workbook is opened.

```
Sub create_graphs()
    Dim wsInput As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim LRowO As Long, LRowI As Long
    Dim LColO As Long, LColI As Long
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim LastChartRow As Integer

    Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")
    
    With wsOutput
        LRowI = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        LColI = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        LastChartRow = LRowI + 3
        For Count = 2 To LRowI
            .Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
            ActiveChart.PlotBy = xlRows
            ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(.Cells(Count, 1), .Cells(Count,LColI))
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(1,LColI))
            ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelOutSideEnd)
            ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = .Cells(Count, 1).Value
            ActiveChart.Parent.Left = .Cells(LRowI + 5, 2).Left
            ActiveChart.Parent.Top = .Cells(LastChartRow, 2).Top
            LastChartRow = LastChartRow + 15
        Next Count
    End With
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call create_graphs
End Sub
```

When I open the Excel workbook, it throws error message `Object variable or With block variable not set` and the graphs are not plotted. Checking from [VB guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set) seems like it's variable issue. Please help to point out the mistake.

Comment: On which line this error is raised? What values does the variables `LRowI` and `LColI` when stopped on error? Are they the one you are expected to be?

Comment: Your code doesn't give me any errors (when run with no data).  Nonetheless, try putting [`Option Explicit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement) at the very top of the module, and then recompile (Debug->Compile) and see which error(s) you get (and where).

Comment: Are you sure this is the code throwing the error?  Another troubleshooting step would be to copy only the relevant code and data into a new workbook and see if it runs there (à la [mcve])

Comment: Missing a couple of "." eg `Source:=.Range(.Cells(Count, 1), .Cells(Count,LColI))`  May not be the problem but worth fixing.  Also before setting a chart title it's worth adding `ActiveChart.HasTitle = True` in case there's currently no title element.

Answer (score 0):

Is your sub on the workbook page in the visual editor? If not it needs to be on the same page or in a module vba will not call a sub from a different page.